# Disable options in 'More' tableview of Tab Bar. ISSUE: Double bar at the bottom for VCs in 'More' tableview of tabbar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a Tab Bar VC that has eight tabs. Four of which, of course, are automatically shifted to the 'More' table.

Each tab VC is embedded in a Navigation Controller.

Firstly, I would like to **disable** some options in the **More** tableview of the tabbar. i.e. User interaction is off for particular cells in the tableview.

Secondly, a problem I'm facing is that when a VC in the **More** tableview is selected, the displayed VC has **TWO** Bars at the bottom(as seen in image). The lowest one is the TabBar. Which is ok. However another Extra bar appears above the TabBar. Why is this appearing and how can I fix the issue?

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: please put ur relavent code here :)

Comment: if (indexPath.row == RowNumber)
        {
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        } for perticular row desable